# iOS (Xcode) open links from webview in external Safari with apple-mobile-web-app-capable

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

Well, I have an app that is just a web view that loads a website. I would like that, when I click on a link, that link opens in a new Safari window BUT recognizing the `'apple-mobile-web-app-capable'` meta tag I have on that new site, just as if I would have added that site to the home screen.

Is that possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the delegate methods of the WebView -

> - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView  shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
>     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;

Where you can check the URL pattern and return NO and open that URL in safari programatically.